# Unable to deploy artifact to nexus on jgitflow:release-finish from bamboo

Tags: maven, nexus, bamboo, jgitflow-maven-plugin, bamboo-artifacts

I am setting up the jgitflow release tasks on bamboo for the first time. We have the nexus url defined in the parent pom and the below jgitflow configuration for a project inherited from it as below

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scmCommentPrefix>[RELEASE] </scmCommentPrefix>
                    <pushReleases>true</pushReleases>
                    <pushFeatures>true</pushFeatures>
                    <pushHotfixes>true</pushHotfixes>
                    <noFeatureBuild>true</noFeatureBuild>
                    <noReleaseBuild>true</noReleaseBuild>
                    <noHotfixBuild>true</noHotfixBuild>
                    <keepBranch>false</keepBranch>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <allowUntracked>true</allowUntracked>
                    <pullDevelop>true</pullDevelop>
                    <pullMaster>true</pullMaster>
                    <allowSnapshots>true</allowSnapshots>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

While the develop and master versiongs/tags are created and updated when I run the jgitflow:release-finish, the artifact that is built is not being pushed into the configured nexus server. Can anyone tell me if there is a certain bamboo thing I am missing or if there is anything wrong with jgitflow configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and resolved it.
I have noReleaseBuild defaulted to true in the jgitflow config (in pom.xml) to avoid building locally, but for the release-finish on bamboo, I am overriding the value by passing -DnoReleaseBuild=true. Unfortunately from the logs (after enabling via -X), I see that the finish task is not overriding the noReleaseBuild defaulted on pom.xml, due to which the release build is never deployed.
I removed the default config that I added in pom.xml and that resulted in pushing the artifacts to nexus configured url on parent pom.